# Trying to chat (right now) but the other person doesn't have enough rep

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, reputation, chat

I'd *like* to "move this conversation to chat" for lengthy related convo to help solve an issue but the other person has 2 rep.

Yet I have enough rep to create a chat room and invite them.

**Is there any way around this?**  Otherwise this is gonna be a real pain.

Comment: I've moved that particular convo to chat and I have added write permissions for the low rep user.